# What is the specific validation error when validationError=true in an openFaces component

Tags: javascript, html, openfaces, validationerror, datechooser

I'm using openFaces' dateChooser and I set a pattern.
If I put in it a wrong value (like: 33/33/33) and try to submit the validationError is set to true because of the wrong format but I don't know how to get the specific error message or component that caused the validation error.

Here is a part of my code:

```
<o:dateChooser 
    id="DateColBtnGeneralView" 
    pattern="#{configurationController.defaultDateFormat}"
    value="#{homeController.firstDate}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="#{configurationController.defaultDateFormat}"/>   
</o:dateChooser>

<o:commandButton
    action="#{homeController.submitDates}"
    onsuccess="contractClientDialogValidation(event)
    value="Submit" />

function contractClientDialogValidation (event) {
    if (event.validationError) {
        alert("I want to show you the right error message according to the wrong value and component");
    }
}
```

The validationError is set to true in case a required component is left empty or in case of an incorrect date format  or in case an input number is too long or etc.

Answer (score 0):

The validation errors are primarily related to the UpdateModelValues and InvokeApplication phases within the JSF lifecycle.

Inside your <h:form/> element you can choose to have a <h:messages id="errorMessages"/> tag.

When the ajax request/response lifecycle is complete, render the <h:messages/> tag.

[See point 3 of this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked)

Comment: I tried to add  <h:message but it didn't work.
After I put the dateChooser with the message in a <h:panelGroup it showed the error messages but it doesn't look nice, it moves all the other components.
I wanted to do it with <o:floatingIconMessage but unfortunately it doesn't work.